# php: date conversion to dd-mm-YYYY format

Tags: php, sql, oracle, date, timestamp

I'm trying to convert this timestamp format which I got from an Oracle sql query:

```
19-SEP-11 02.34.51.558459 PM
```

I need to convert it to this format: dd-mm-YYYY.

```
$install_date=strtotime($install_date);
$install_date=date("d/m/Y",strtotime($install_date));
```

but I'm getting weird results...

Any ideas?

```
*** forgot to mention, the field type is TIMESTAMP and not DATETIME
```

Comment: Please post your weird results so we don't all have to fire up a PHP interpreter and do it ourselves.

Comment: Do you have any control over the query used? Ideally you should do a `TO_CHAR` on the date field to get what you want.

Comment: Will it work also on timestamp field?

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with formats that `strtotime()` cannot handle (see [supported date and time formats](http://php.net/datetime.formats)), or even if you are, then you can create a `DateTime` object from any format using `DateTime::createFromFormat()` (or it's procedural twin, `date_create_from_format()`) ([docs](http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat)).

```
$install_date = '19-SEP-11 02.34.51.558459 PM';
$datetime     = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-y h.i.s.u A', $install_date);
$datetime_dmy = $datetime->format('d/m/Y');
```

Comment: @rfausak of course. I don't support legacy software, PHP included.

Comment: @AviLevin I'm sorry. On several different levels.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a datetime field in Oracle, you could use

```
TO_CHAR(fieldName, 'DD-MM-YYY')
```

In your select, then it would be formatted as it comes out of the database.

Comment: Let Oracle do the heavy lifting as it is faster than PHP at manipulating data.

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

```
$install_date=strtotime($install_date);
$install_date=date("d/m/Y",$install_date);
```

You had already converted `$install_date` to internal time, then you were doing it again in the second line.

Of course, you can cut it all down to one line if you like:

```
$install_date=date("d/m/Y",strtotime($install_date));
```

Comment: @halfdan, the code assumes the same as the original post, that `$install_date` had been previously loaded. It's just a code snippet, not the whole thing.

Comment: The date format OP posted isn't parsed correctly by `strtotime()`

Comment: Tried it, got 1/1/1970 like @halfdan wrote.